# Call setState() from main() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

How do I call the setState() method of a specific State-Class after every Cron-Job I call in my main() ?

Main():

```
void main() async {
    new Cron().schedule(new Schedule.parse('* * * * *'), () async {
        uploadDocuments();
    });

    runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: MainMenu(),
    ));
}
```

Class, where I want setState() to be called:

```
class DbObjectsDetails extends StatefulWidget 

    @override
    _DbObjectsDetailsState createState() => _DbObjectsDetailsState();
}

class _DbObjectsDetailsState extends State<DbObjectsDetails> {

    void initState() {
        loadFilesFromDatabase(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't set the state directly. You could set up a [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html), call a method on it which in turn notifies the listeners. In your Widget, listen to it and set the state when you are notified.

Comment: Or use RiverPod.  Rather trivial there to update a value and get rebuilt when it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`get_it`](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package to register a singleton of `GlobalKey` and then use it in both places

This code may work:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

GetIt locator = GetIt.instance..allowReassignment = true;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => GlobalKey<DbObjectsDetailsState>());
}

GlobalKey<DbObjectsDetailsState> newWidgetKey() {
  locator.registerSingleton(GlobalKey<DbObjectsDetailsState>());
  return locator<GlobalKey<DbObjectsDetailsState>>();
}

void main() async {
  setupLocator()
  new Cron().schedule(new Schedule.parse('* * * * *'), () async {
    //you can acces the current state of the widget like that:
    locator<GlobalKey<DbObjectsDetailsState>>().currentState?.rebuild();});
    
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: DbObjectsDetails(key: newWidgetKey()),
      ));
    }
    
    class DbObjectsDetails extends StatefulWidget {
      DbObjectsDetails({Key key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      DbObjectsDetailsState createState() => DbObjectsDetailsState();
    }
    
    class DbObjectsDetailsState extends State<DbObjectsDetails> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    
      void rebuild() => setState((){})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use state in a stateful widget. The main function is not a widget it's a dart function. So there is no way that you can use setState() function inside the main function.